# Panda Dataframe Resampling based on column criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I want to resample a dataframe if cell in another column matches my criteria

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'timestamp': [
            '2013-03-01 08:01:00', '2013-03-01 08:02:00',
            '2013-03-01 08:03:00', '2013-03-01 08:04:00',
            '2013-03-01 08:05:00', '2013-03-01 08:06:00'
        ],
        'Kind': [
            'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'
        ],
        'Values': [1, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 3]
    })
```

For every timestamp, I may have 2-10 kinds, and I want to resample correctly without producing `NaN`. Currently I resample on the entire dataframe using below code and get `NaNs`. I think it's due to I have multiple entries for certain timestamps.

```
df.set_index('timestamp').resample('5Min').mean()
```

One method is to create different dataframes for every kind, resample every dataframe, and join the resulting dataframes. I'd like to find out if there's any simple way of doing it.

Comment: `df.groupby('Kind').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('timestamp').resample('5Min').mean()).reset_index()`?

Comment: @Abdou This code is giving an error.

Comment: @ShankarPandala what kind of error? I just used the provided sample dataframe. You want to make sure your `timestamp` is of `datetime` objects.

Comment: @Abdou it's a syntax error stating "invalid character in identifier". error is point at x.set_index

Comment: It's from the way you are copying and pasting the code. Instead, write the code itself. Multiline comments that contain code are hard to copy and paste.

Answer (score 7):

After defining your dataframe as you stated, you should transform `timestamp` column to `datetime` first. Then set it as the index and finally resampling and finding the mean as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'timestamp': [
            '2013-03-01 08:01:00', '2013-03-01 08:02:00',
            '2013-03-01 08:03:00', '2013-03-01 08:04:00',
            '2013-03-01 08:05:00', '2013-03-01 08:06:00'
        ],
        'Kind': [
            'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'
        ],
        'Values': [1, 1.5, 2, 3, 5, 3]
    })

df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df = df.set_index(["timestamp"])
df = df.resample("5Min")    
print df.mean()
```

This would print the mean you expect:

```
>>> 
Values    2.75
```

And your dataframe would result in:

```
>>> df
                     Values
timestamp                  
2013-03-01 08:05:00     2.5
2013-03-01 08:10:00     3.0
```

**Grouping by kind**

If you want to group by kind and get the mean of each Kind (means A and B) you can do as follows:

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df = df.set_index(["timestamp"])
gb = df.groupby(["Kind"])
df = gb.resample("5Min")
print df.xs("A", level = "Kind").mean()
print df.xs("B", level = "Kind").mean()
```

As result you would get:

```
>>> 
Values    2.666667
Values    2.625
```

And your dataframe would finally look as:

```
>>> df
                            Values
Kind timestamp                    
A    2013-03-01 08:05:00  2.666667
B    2013-03-01 08:05:00  2.250000
     2013-03-01 08:10:00  3.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is better practice to explicitly convert `'timestamp'` column to `DatetimeIndex` type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': pd.to_datetime([
        '2013-03-01 08:01:00', '2013-03-01 08:02:00',
        '2013-03-01 08:03:00', '2013-03-01 08:04:00',
        '2013-03-01 08:05:00', '2013-03-01 08:06:00']),
    'Kind':   ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'Values': [ 1,  4.5,  2,   7,   5,   9] })
```

Please put attention to the changed values of `B` kind. Now, when you resample `mean()` estimates the new value as average of two existing ones. It might happen that more than one new data points fall between existing ones, and `pandas` fills their values with `NaNs`. You can use `ffill()` or `bfill()`, depending on whether side of the time interval you wish to be closed. By default it is left, so `bfill()` is the choice.

```
 df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('Kind').resample('1.5Min')['Values'].bfill().reset_index()

Out[1]:

    Kind    timestamp       Values
0   A   2013-03-01 08:00:00 1.0
1   A   2013-03-01 08:01:30 2.0
2   A   2013-03-01 08:03:00 2.0
3   A   2013-03-01 08:04:30 5.0
4   B   2013-03-01 08:01:30 4.5
5   B   2013-03-01 08:03:00 7.0
6   B   2013-03-01 08:04:30 9.0
7   B   2013-03-01 08:06:00 9.0
```

It will use last observed value to fill the `NaNs`.

If you wish to interpolate the values, and not just to fill the gaps, use `transform(pd.Series.interpolate)` combo. The `transform` will apply `interpolate()` function on each group. Try resampling with higher frequency (say 10 seconds), you will see the big difference between two approaches.

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('Kind').resample('1.5Min').mean().transform(pd.Series.interpolate).reset_index()

Out[2]:

    Kind    timestamp       Values
0   A   2013-03-01 08:00:00 1.0
1   A   2013-03-01 08:01:30 1.5
2   A   2013-03-01 08:03:00 2.0
3   A   2013-03-01 08:04:30 5.0
4   B   2013-03-01 08:01:30 4.5
5   B   2013-03-01 08:03:00 7.0
6   B   2013-03-01 08:04:30 8.0
7   B   2013-03-01 08:06:00 9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp') # Set your index.
df.index = df.index.astype('datetime64') # Set to DatetimeIndex (Index doesn't work with resample)
df.resample('5Min').mean() # Do the actual resampling.
```

This returns a dataframe with 2 rows as you would expect:

```
                    Values
timestamp                  
2013-03-01 08:00:00   1.875
2013-03-01 08:05:00   4.000
```

Your "Kind" column is dropped because it doesn't make sense to take mean of characters. If you wanted to keep it, you would have to introduce a new rule (for example assign the most frequent character for the given period).

Answer (score 0):

set timestamp to type datetime and then use as the index.

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df = df.set_index(["timestamp"])
```

sample from columns of your own choice, eg: sample from kind A:

```
df[df.Kind=='A'].sample(1)

 Kind  Values
timestamp                       
2013-03-01 08:03:00    A     2.0
```

sample then do calculation:

```
df[df.Kind=='A'].sample(2).mean()
Values    1.5
dtype: float64
```